# Trying to write a macro using SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA that copy pastes a formula and data validation but not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, copy-paste, macro-recorder

I have a google form and the responses are being recorded in a google sheet. I want to add some data processing to the cells following the responses, such as changing the timestamp to week number, timestamp as year, days since submission.
So I have the formulas in my example row, row 2.
And i'm trying to copy them into the last row with data.

| Timestamp | Formula 1 (Column L) | Formula 2 (Column M) | Formula 3 (Column N) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Timestamp 1 | formula 1 | formula 2 | formula 3 |
| Timestamp 2 | Blank | Blank | Blank |

In both attempts below I am getting the data validation copied, but the formulas don't copy and the cells remain blank.
I first tried modifying an existing macro.

```
function Copypaste() 
{
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses');
  var lastrow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  sheet1.getRange(lastrow, 12).activate();
  sheet1.getRange(2, 12, 1, 15).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
  sheet1.getRange(2, 12, 1, 15).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);
};
```

And then I tried recording a Macro.

```
function CopyFormula() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L12').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('L2:Q2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('L2:Q2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
};
```

As far as I can tell, they are essentially the same. I can run my recorded Macro and it works, but my modyified macro doesn't. Why?

Comment: `spreadsheet` is not defined in the first script.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to fix it. 



`
    function Copypaste() 
{
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses');
  var lastrow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  sheet1.getRange(lastrow, 14).activate();
  sheet1.getRange(2, 14, 1, 19).copyTo(sheet1.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
  sheet1.getRange(2, 14, 1, 19).copyTo(sheet1.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);
  sheet1.getRange('N:AF').activate();
  sheet1.getActiveRangeList().setHorizontalAlignment('center');
}; `